# Dynamically add children to React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add child components to existing React components dynamically over an id system. To do so I have a list of components, in which new components are stored with an id, before the component is rendered. With this list I can get the component by id and call the `addChild()` function of it. The component gets rerendered afterwards. Child components can be of any type, not just ComponentWithChilds, this is just an example.

```
components = {};

  var ComponentWithChilds = React.createClass({
    getInitialState : function(){
      components[this.props.id] = this;  //saves the component into the list
      return {children : []};
    },
    addChild : function(child){
      this.state.children.push(child);
      this.setState({
        children : this.state.children
      });
    },
    render : function(){
      return React.createElement("div",{},this.state.children);
    }
  });

  ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(ComponentWithChilds, {id:"id1"}),
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
  components["id1"].addChild(React.createElement(ComponentWithChilds, {id:"id2"}));  //adds a child to the element with id: "id1"
```

People are saying this is an anti-pattern and I can understand them, because this breaks some principles of React. So what is the best way to achieve this the react-friendly way?

Comment: Can you tell about the reason why would you want to render components outside of the render function?

Comment: I don't want to render them outside of the render function. Just add children to a component via its id and then trigger the rerendering so the changes will apply.